# C, matrix transposed multiplication using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, transpose

I'm trying to transpose and multiply some matrices, basically
I get 2 matrices, `matrixA` and `matrixB` the action to be performed is `trace(transpose(matrixA)*matrixB)`.

I managed to get this working for `nxn` matrices but I can't get it to work with `mxn` where (`n>m` or `m>n`).

I've looked online for solutions but I can't implement theirs solution into mine.

I removed almost all the code to simplify reading, if you prefer the entire code [I linked it here.](https://pastebin.com/3exdr8Av)

If you do want to run the entire code, to recreate the problem use the following commands:

```
zeroes matrixA 2 3
zeroes matrixB 2 3
set matrixA
1 2 3 4 5 6
set matrixB
6 5 4 3 2 1
frob matrixA matrixB
```

The above commands should return Sum `56` but instead I get Sum `18`

```
int* matrixATransposed = (int*) malloc(matrixARowLenght * matrixAColLenght * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < matrixARowLenght; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixAColLenght; j++)
    {
        *(matrixATransposed + i * matrixAColLenght + j) = *(matrixA + j * matrixAColLenght + i);
    }
}
// Multiply
int* mulRes = (int*)malloc(matrixARowLenght * matrixAColLenght * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < matrixAColLenght; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixBColLenght; j++) {
        *(mulRes + i * matrixARowLenght + j) = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < matrixARowLenght; k++)
            *(mulRes + i * matrixAColLenght + j) += *(matrixATransposed + i * matrixAColLenght + k) * *(matrixB + k * matrixBColLenght + j);
    }
}
// Sum the trace
int trace = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matrixARowLenght; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixAColLenght; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            trace += *(mulRes + i * matrixAColLenght + j);
        }
    }
}
printf_s("Sum: %d\n", trace);
```

Comment: Perhaps if you added some intermediate `printf`'s to show you the results of the intermediate calculations the problem would become clearer.

Comment: 1. You need to decide whether you are representing your matrices as row major order or column major order -- because you are confusing yourself (in code your provided link).  If you have a matrix `A` with `numARows` and `numACols` for a total of `numARows * numACols` elements and you see iteration like: `for(i=0; i < numACols; ++i) for(j=0; j < numARows; ++j) A[i*numACols+j])` -- then you know something is wrong -- because `i` needs to be on the range of 0 to numARows-1 to make it work.  Remember the last element is numARows*numACols-1 = (numARows-1)*numACols + (numACols-1).

Comment: 2. I'd create temporary variables `int matrixATransposedRowLength=matrixAColLength`, and also for `matrixATransposedColLength`, `resRowLength`, and `resColLength`. and use them.

Comment: 3. You don't need nested loops for trace.  One loop will suffice.

Comment: 4.  Remember to free your memory.

Comment: This is what I mean ... look: `*(mulRes + i * matrixARowLenght + j) = 0;` here you are initializing your destination to zero before the sum.  And here you are summing in your destination  `*(mulRes + i * matrixAColLenght + j) += ... ` Notice they are different elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array indices for calculating the transpose, multiplication, and the trace seem to be incorrect. I've corrected them in the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int matrixARowLenght = 2;
    int matrixAColLenght = 3;
    int matrixA[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    int matrixBRowLenght = 2;
    int matrixBColLenght = 3; 
    int matrixB[] = {6,5,4,3,2,1};

    // Transpose
    int* matrixATransposed = (int *) malloc(matrixARowLenght * matrixAColLenght * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixAColLenght; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixARowLenght; j++) {
            *(matrixATransposed + i * matrixARowLenght + j) = *(matrixA + j * matrixAColLenght + i);
        }
    }

    // Multiply
    int *mulRes = (int *) malloc(matrixARowLenght * matrixAColLenght * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixAColLenght; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixAColLenght; ++j) {
            *(mulRes + (i * matrixAColLenght) + j) = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < matrixARowLenght; ++k) {
                *(mulRes + (i * matrixAColLenght) + j) += *(matrixATransposed + (i * matrixARowLenght) + k) * *(matrixB + (k * matrixAColLenght) + j);
            } 
        }
    }
    free(matrixATransposed);

    // Sum the trace
    int trace = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixAColLenght; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixAColLenght; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                trace += *(mulRes + i * matrixAColLenght + j);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sum: %d\n", trace);
    free(mulRes);

    return 0;
}
```

The above program will output your expected value:

```
Sum: 56
```

---

** **UPDATE** **
As pointed by MFisherKDX, the above code will not work if the result matrix is not a square matrix. The following code fixes this issue:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int matrixARowLenght = 2;
    int matrixAColLenght = 3;
    int matrixA[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    int matrixBRowLenght = 2;
    int matrixBColLenght = 4; 
    int matrixB[] = {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

    // Transpose
    int* matrixATransposed = (int *) malloc(matrixARowLenght * matrixAColLenght * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixAColLenght; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixARowLenght; j++) {
            *(matrixATransposed + i * matrixARowLenght + j) = *(matrixA + j * matrixAColLenght + i);
        }
    }

    // Multiply
    int *mulRes = (int *) malloc(matrixAColLenght * matrixBColLenght * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixAColLenght; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixBColLenght; ++j) {
            *(mulRes + (i * matrixBColLenght) + j) = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < matrixARowLenght; ++k) {
                *(mulRes + (i * matrixBColLenght) + j) += *(matrixATransposed + (i * matrixARowLenght) + k) * *(matrixB + (k * matrixBColLenght) + j);
            } 
        }
    }
    free(matrixATransposed);

    // Sum the trace
    int trace = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixAColLenght; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixBColLenght; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                trace += *(mulRes + i * matrixBColLenght + j);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sum: %d\n", trace);
    free(mulRes);

    return 0;
}
```

This code will output the following as expected:

```
Sum: 83
```

Comment: This only works because your result matrix is square. For instance, your loop indexes out of bounds when the result matrix has more columns than rows.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed this issue in my updated post.